# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I am giving condition by select query and store in a variable and in that condition I am giving the insert query at that time this issues is coming

Here is my query

```
create table #temp
(
    productid int
) 

--Insert into #temp
Insert into #temp
    select Product.Id 
    from Product 
    left join mysql_abc_Product on mysql_abc_Product.ProductId = Product.ID
    where mysql_abc_Product.ProductId is NULL

Declare @maxCount int = (select count(productId) from #temp)

WHILE(@i <= @maxCount)
BEGIN
    select * from #temp

    declare @ModelID int
    SET @ModelID = (select DISTINCT tmp.ProductId, s.Id, l.Id 
                    from Language l, Store s, #temp tmp, Product p 
                    left join mysql_abc_Product isp on isp.ProductId = p.Id  
                    where isp.Id is NULL 
                      and p.Deleted = 'False' 
                       or p.Published = 'True' 
                       or VisibleIndividually = 'True')

    if(@ModelID > 0)
        Insert into mysql_abc_Product(ProductId, SolrStatus, IsDeleted, InTime, StoreId, LanguageId) 
            select DISTINCT 
                tmp.ProductId, 1, 0, GETDATE(), s.Id, l.Id 
            from  
                Language l, Store s, #temp tmp, Product p 
            left join 
                mysql_abc_Product isp on isp.ProductId = p.Id  
            where 
                isp.Id is NULL 
    else
        Insert into mysql_abc_Product(ProductId, SolrStatus, IsDeleted, InTime, StoreId, LanguageId) 
            select DISTINCT 
                tmp.ProductId, 1, 0, GETDATE(), s.Id, l.Id 
            from  
                Language l, Store s, #temp tmp, Product p 
            left join 
                mysql_abc_Product isp on isp.ProductId = p.Id  
            where 
                isp.Id is NULL 

        SET @i  = @i  + 1
    END

    drop table #temp
END
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And you should ***most definitely NOT*** mix them!!